# ubuntu 18.04 boot problem: Logo keeps flashing

Tags: 18.04

I've been using ubuntu 18.04 in a dual boot system since the release after automatically upgrading from 16.04. The last 1 month i have this problem. After choosing ubuntu from boot menu it takes more than usual (disk is reading) to load ubuntu logo. Then for every loading bullet the logo disappears and then it appears again. This happens all the time and it doesn't boot. However it boots ok when using the recovery mode.

Answer (score -1):

Kindly go to single user mode for checking boot and Journalctl logs in order to take action according error/warning what logs say.

commands for log files:-

```
#cat /var/log/boot.log

#journalctl -xe
```

Comment: how to go to single user mode;